# Distribution of Sums Confidence Interval

Tags: statistical-significance, lognormal-distribution, weighted-data

How do I find a confidence interval for a series of values that are log-normally distributed weighted by their values?

The distribution would look like:

$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{mU_k}$

Where U is a random variable between 0 and 1, and n is the number of samples and m is some scale factor greater than 1.

I have found similar questions which have suggested working with mean and then multiplying by n ([Confidence interval on sum of estimates vs. estimate of whole?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241678/confidence-interval-on-sum-of-estimates-vs-estimate-of-whole)), however this would not work with my distribution. There may often be large influxes of small numbers, which disappear when flattened into a histogram where each range is logarithmic (1 to 2, 2 to 4, 4 to 8, etc) and each bar is the sum, and so small numbers should not influence my distribution by more than their weight.

My weighted distribution looks like:
[image: Sums]

If all my samples were weighted equally (as opposed to by their value) the distribution would look like:
[image: Counts]
As you can see if I weight all points equally it makes the 8192 to 16384 range look equal in value to the 1024 to 2048 range, which in reality it is about 9 times more important. These small ranges cannot influence the distribution more than their sum.

Edit: U is a random variable between 0 and 1, and n is the number of samples.

Comment: You need to define U$_k$..  Also I am not sure what you mean by estimate of whole.